# WooCommerce get variable product attribute label

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to display the details from my custom product attributes on a table on my single product page. I can get the product variation SKU, but I can't seem to get the "label" (the best I can do is get the slug).

This is the code that I'm currently working with:

```
<!-- ******* START PRODUCT VARIABLE TABLE SECTION ******* -->
<?php
global $woocommerce, $product, $post;

if( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) :

  $available_variations = $product->get_available_variations();

  // START CHECK IF VARIATIONS ARE PRESENT
  if ( $available_variations ) :

  $attributes = $product->get_attributes();
?>

<div class="row">
    <div class="small-12 column">
        <table class="varations-table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="small-4">ORDER #</th>
                    <th class="small-5">DESCRIPTION</th>
                    <th class="small-3">UOM</th>        
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>

            <?php foreach ($available_variations as $prod_variation) : ?>

                <?php
                    // get some vars to work with
                    $post_id = $prod_variation['variation_id'];
                    $post_object = get_post($post_id);
                ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $prod_variation['sku']; ?></td>

                <?php foreach ($prod_variation['attributes'] as $attr_name => $attr_value) : ?>
                    <td><?php echo $attr_value; ?></td>
                <?php endforeach;?>

                    <td class="uom"><?php echo the_field( 'uom' ); ?></td>

                </tr>
            <?php endforeach;?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>

<?php
    // END CHECK IF VARIATIONS ARE PRESENT
    endif;
endif;
?>
<!-- ******* END PRODUCT VARIABLE TABLE SECTION ******* -->
```

Does anyone know how I can pull the Variable label (not just the slug, replacing dashes with spaces using str_replace() )?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have the slug, you can get a WordPress taxonomy object with the [`get_taxonomy()` function](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_taxonomy). So to get the label of a WooCommerce custom attribute you just have to do `get_taxonomy($attribute_slug)->labels->name`.

Comment: That is embarrassingly simple. I'm actually quite ashamed that I didn't think of that in the first place. lol Thanks for your help

Comment: I cant' see anything in Woocommerce that can be defined "simple". A whole data structure for an attribute and still no label in it.

Answer (score -1):

```
    <?php if ( $product->is_type( 'variable'  )) : ?>
                <div class="size">
                    <span class="name-size">SIZE</span>
                    <span class="value-size">
                        <?php
                        $attr = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_product_attributes', true);
                        echo $attr['size']['value'];
                        ?>
                    </span>
                </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
```